# Simplest an fastest C# Expression that always evaluates to false and does not generate a compiler warning

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have a rather esotheric case where I need to have some piece of code that will never execute but which still needs to be part of the compilation output. Although I could come up with my own, I'm asking the community: What is the simplest and fastest C# Expression that always evaluates to false and does not generate a compiler warning and preserves the enclosed block of code in the final build output?

**Update:** Since explaining the rationale behind the question was requested: The Monotouch linker performs static code analysis in order to strip all unreferenced symbols out of the final build to decrease the size of the generated binaries. This poses a problem with properties only accessed through reflection.

Comment: Would you mind explaining where this would be needed? It sounds rather interesting.

Comment: "Although I could come up with my own" - OK, let's see it....

Comment: @MitchWheat My own solution was pretty similar to Matthew Watson's.

Comment: You should ask Monotouch devs, they might have a solution for you (adding a custom attribute for instance).

Comment: To solve the actual problem you could create a class that reads the properties. That way you do not have to bother with false tests. This class might prevent the removal of the properties.

Comment: [According to the docs, you don't need this at all.](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking) You can use [`[Preserve]`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Runtime.PreserveAttribute), and if that for some reason doesn't work for you, it already documents a supported workaround: a `bool` variable that you never set to `true`.

Comment: @Guillaume There's a solution in place for that. It's called the Preserve attribute. But the Monotouch linker also optimizes symbols in the base class libraries which I obviously cannot decorate. This is a good thing because it safes a lot of space but can cause problems with reflection heavy code.

Comment: @hvd Please see my response to Guillaume above

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Please also see the second part of my comment :)

Comment: @OliverWeichhold maybe with custom linking ? http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker#3.custom-linking

Comment: @hvd Good point. But no MonoTouch is for iOS. MonoDroid is for Android.

Comment: @Guillaume Custom linking would be an option but I'd rather maintain my symbol dependencies and the code depending on them in one code file (static initializer for fake references).

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Oops, sorry about that. I do expect it to work even with Monotouch though.

Comment: what about the [`-nolinkaway`](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker) option, would it work for your case?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit That seems the way to go - especially when you read the bit about Custom Linking: *"You can provide extra definitions to the linker to ensure the type, methods and/or fields are not eliminated from your application"* seems perfect for the OP's stated goal. I'd consider making that an answer. :)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit After thinking about it I tend to agree with you that a custom link XML definition would be the way to go.

Comment: Oops I didn't notice that @Guillaume had already mentioned custom linking. Looks like he was first. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go for simple...

```
public static bool False() {
    return false;
}
public static void Foo() {
    if (False()) {
       ...
    }
}
```

If you need to convince JIT too (inlining), then add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` to `False()`

Comment: Marc, are you sure the compiler won't be able to spot that?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold pretty sure, yes. Feel free to check. If you wanted **cast iron** - call a `virtual` property/method. The compiler can't ever remove that, because a subclass could do something different.

Answer (score 5):

[Second edit]

It seems to me that @Guillaume has suggested the correct answer in comments to the OP, where he suggests that the OP should use custom linking to ensure that the properties in question do not get optimised away: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker#3.custom-linking

If @Guillaume writes that as an answer, I will remove this edit so that he can rightly get credit.

---

Original answer:

How about:

```
if ("".Length > 0)
```

I checked this code in reflector for a release build (VS2012, .Net 4.5)

```
void Run()
{
    if ("".Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

and it produces this IL:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void Run() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldstr ""
    L_0005: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::get_Length()
    L_000a: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000b: ble L_0015
    L_0010: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

---

EDIT: Since there seems to be some debate about whether this will work, let me offer some more evidence.

The goal is to ensure that a property is accessed by the generated code.

Given this C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        void Run()
        {
            if ("".Length > 0)
            {
                Test t = new Test();
                Trace.WriteLine(t.Property); // Make sure we use the property.
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Test
    {
        public int Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The IL code generated for the `Run()` method for a release build is:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void Run() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 5
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication1.Test t)
    L_0000: ldstr ""
    L_0005: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::get_Length()
    L_000a: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000b: ble L_0026
    L_0010: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test::.ctor()
    L_0015: stloc.0 
    L_0016: ldloc.0 
    L_0017: callvirt instance int32 ConsoleApplication1.Test::get_Property()
    L_001c: box int32
    L_0021: call void [System]System.Diagnostics.Trace::WriteLine(object)
    L_0026: ret 
}
```

So the property is definitely being referenced in the output code; thus, this fulfils the requirement.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Wanna bet? :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, ILSpy is showing it as optimized away when build in release mode

Comment: @Habib I checked a release build with Reflector, and it's not being optimized away.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `var x = obj.prop;` should never be optimised away, as (even if it's poor practise) the property getter might have side effects.

Comment: If the could inside the if() is not optimized away it will be seen by the monotouch static code analysis and thus preserve the symbol.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit The requirement is "preserves the enclosed block of code in the final build output", which this clearly does - just look at the IL that's generated from my test code. The `Console.WriteLine()` is still there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think that testing an object reference == null when you know that it's not null would be the fastest.

**Update**.  Looking at some of the other answers, my guess is that anything that's clearly false on a stand alone is more at risk of being optimised away (if not today, then perhaps in the future) compared to something that you know from the logic of your program must be false.  And in terms of the low level opcodes, testing something != 0 is one of the fastest operations that I know.

Answer (score 2):

maybe filedlike this

```
 volatile bool val = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just trying to be creative here (not suggesting anything that has been suggested before), perhaps:

```
if (new object().GetType() == typeof(string))
```

I don't think that will be optimized away, but I'm not really in a place where I could test that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(false)
{
}
```

... would be my guess :)

Comment: @MitchWheat, good point.  I'll leave the answer here, however, so others can see why it's not a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try using `if(1 == 2) {...}`, is that what you want?
```

**Edit**: 
I think below one should not be detected by the compiler:

```
if(this.GetType().ToString().Equals(string.Empty)
{
    ......
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the compiler will be able to spot that.